# Same first and last letter in array C

Tags: arrays, c, string, character

My assignment is to write a C program, in which user inputs a sentence, and the program checks if there are words that begin and end with the same letter (for example **e**y**e**, **r**oa**r**, **s**o**s** etc.)
I wrote this and I am not sure it will work

I've also got an error: uninitialized local variable 'p2' used. May someone say where I should initialize it?

> Maybe someone can add some tips for improving?

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    char arr[MAX];
    char* p1, *p2;
    int sym, i;
    printf("\n\t Enter your sentence(use .(dot) or Enter to finish input):");
    while ((sym = getchar()) != '.' && sym != '\n' && i < MAX)
    {
        arr[i++] = sym; //symbols to array
        arr[i] = '0';   
    }

    p1 = arr;   //pointer for 1st symbol
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == ',' || arr[i] == ' ') //finding a word
        {
            *p2 = arr[i--];
            if (*p1 = *p2) //if first and last letters are equal
            {
                printf("%s", arr);
            }
            if (arr[i++] == ',' || arr[i++] == ' ')
            {
                *p1 = arr[i + 2];
            }
            *p1 = arr[i++];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: `if (*p1 = *p2)` doesn't compare, it copies the value from `*p2` to `*p1`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `i` should be initialized, `i = 0;` otherwise `i` starts from some random value. You can just use `fgets` to read input, then use `strcspn` to remove the last `\n` character.

```
*p2 = arr[i--];
```

`p2` is declared as a pointer and again is not initialized. It's pointing to some random address in memory and should not be dereferenced yet.

If you are not experienced enough with pointers, you can just use the array style indexing.

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)...
```

`MAX` is the maximum number of characters which can be stored in `arr`. But string's length can be less, it's determined by `strlen`. Example:

```
char arr[MAX];

printf("input:");
fgets(arr, sizeof(arr), stdin);
arr[strcspn(arr, "\n")] = 0;

size_t len = strlen(arr);
if(len == 0) return 0;
if (arr[0] == arr[len - 1])
    printf("first and last match");
else
    printf("first and last don't match");
```

If there are more than one word in `arr`, you can use `strtok` to break `arr` in to words, check each word individually.